# web config authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 30:     </httpHandlers>
Line 31:     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="3145728" />
Line 32:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 33:       <forms loginUrl="~/admin"  timeout="40"/>
Line 34:     </authentication>
```

> Am I need Add web site to IIS for authentication

Answer (score 1):

The `<authentication>` node cannot be inherited. It needs to be defined only once at the top level web.config. Your ASP.NET MVC 3 application needs to be hosted in a virtual directory in IIS or in a separate website.

Comment: You should create a virtual directory in IIS and host your ASP.NET MVC 3 application there. A virtual directory is associated to a physical directory on the server which is where the root of your application resides.

Comment: I try to set static IP for IP Addres and get this error-192.168.0.101:80 is an invalid IP address

Comment: I don't see how this could be related.